# Binding from trigger to object in Collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, triggers, blend

I have an object with these properties:

[image: 1]

IsLightOnVal is a Collection with 2 fields: string for the State name and Bool for the Value, as we can see in the 2nd picture:

[image: 2]

In the ControlTemplate of my Object, I want to create a trigger for: when the value of my first object in my collection is true, then do this....

I can easily access from my property IsLightOnVal1 and IsLightOnVal1 of the 1st picture, but i cannot access to my collection.

So this is working fine:

```
<Trigger Property="IsLightOnVal1" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="tkValue1" Value="{StaticResource Amber}"/>
</Trigger>
```

But when I try something with the collection, I never have access, I tried:

```
<Trigger Property="{Binding IsLightOnVal[0].Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=NameSpace:MyObject}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="tkValue1" Value="{StaticResource Amber}"/>
</Trigger>
```

But the trigger's property doesn't seem to accept binding...

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: The bracket syntax should be valid, are you sure you RelativeSource Path is working ?
Do you have binding errors in the output window?

Comment: Error is: Invalid XAML. That's it... I tried the DataTrigger, no error but doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular `Triggers` are meant to be used on UI Element Properties. If you want to base a trigger on a bound value you need to use a `DataTrigger`

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLightOnVal[0].Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=NameSpace:MyObject}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="tkValue1" Value="{StaticResource Amber}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks to Rachel, the correct code is:

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLightOnVal[0].Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="tkValue1" Value="{StaticResource Amber}"/>
    </DataTrigger>